# transform_reduce & getting rid of a for loop

Tags: c++, std

so I am going through some of my code now and trying to get rid of some for loops I don't like & trying to get more experience with standard algorithms..
So the loop I have now can be explained best by the following code snippet :

```
// Defined struct
struct A {
  /* stuff */
  size_t computed_value() const { /* ... */ return value; }
};

// In other location in code
std::vector<A> vecA;
// ... insert tons of A's into vecA

size_t summed_value = 0;
for(const auto& a : vecA) {
  summed_value += a.computed_value();
}
```

This is the loop I want to replace with a standard algorithm, and I thought I had found the perfect fit.. `std::transform_reduce` in `numeric` header, but it seems that neither my version of clang or g++ has this function included..? 
Some other things I thought of are `std::accumulate` but it requires A be implicitly converted to an int (as far as I can tell) & `std::transform` but I couldn't find any way to use an int or size_t as the output value.

Note : I am only willing to use up to C++17 as of now.

Anyone have any advice on a function I should look into? Thanks!

Comment: Up and _including_ C++17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function should work just fine:

```
size_t summed_value = std::accumulate(begin(vecA), end(vecA), 0, [](size_t acc, A const& a)
{
    return acc + a.computed_value();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have read further into accumulate documentation..